# How to use createEmbeddedView method of TemplateRef in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am starting to learn DOM manipulation in Angular and notice templateRef and its method **createEmbeddedView**. I am more curious to learn about this method. Now all my question is, how to use the createEmbeddedView of this method

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
<ng-template #template>

</ng-template>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
        @ViewChild('template', { read: TemplateRef }) _template: TemplateRef<any>;      
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this._template.createEmbeddedView('this is a embedded view')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create an embedded view using `createEmbeddedView` method then attach that view to the DOM via `ViewContainerRef`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <ng-template #template let-name='fromContext'><div>{{name}}</ng-template>
        <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    @ViewChild('template', { read: TemplateRef }) _template: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        const view = this._template.createEmbeddedView({fromContext: 'John'});
        this.vc.insert(view);
    }
}
```

Or you can create a view using `ViewContainerRef` directly:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this._template, {fromContext: 'John'});
}
```

The context is an object with properties and you can access those properties through `let-` bindings.

To learn more read [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) and also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027581/2545680).

Comment: what would be the context type, will it be a string? and what is vc stands for, is it viewContainerRef?

Comment: yes, i understood that, but my question is what is the "context" type which you have also mentioned in your code.
is it a string which takes the value ie.<div>this is a dynamic element</div>

Comment: @LijinJohn, I just added an example of using context object properties inside the template

Comment: @LijinDurairaj, is there any else unclear about my answer?

Comment: @LijinDurairaj Please mark this as answer, if this answered your question.

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that this answer creates an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error?

Comment: @Skyler, this error is not specific to this approach, it can occur at various circumstances, you can read more about it [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) and [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10)

Comment: For anyone stuck up with `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` use `{static:true}` and pefrom changes in `ngAfterContentInit` cycle

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative(easier) route that produces the same effect as the `createEmbeddedView()`. The next example provides both the short notation and long form notation:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <ng-template #yourTemplateRef let-item="data">
        Data is: {{data}}
    </ng-template>
    <!-- Long notation -->
    <ng-container 
       [ngTemplateOutlet]="yourTemplateRef"
       [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data: data}">
    </ng-container>

 <!-- Short notation -->
    <ng-container 
      *ngTemplateOutlet="yourTemplateRef; context: {data: data}">
    </ng-container>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { data = 123; }
```