# Can't have event on ng-template? Event binding click not emitted by any directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am trying to simply use *ngIf ;else to render a button or not but keep getting this error. It seems I can not have an event on my ng-template?  This can't be so.  I must be doing something obviously wrong.

The event name (click) is obviously spelled correctly and from what I know all directives I need Browser and Common modules are imported and listed in the NgModule metadata.

Error:

> Event binding click not emitted by any directive on an embedded
>   template. Make sure that the event name is spelled correctly and all
>   directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".

This is the only real solution I found for this problem:
[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063686/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div-in-production-buil) but I have BrowserModule and CommonModule both imported into AppModule and the module closest to where the error is occurring.

[image: Event binding click not emitted by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the event name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".]

Very close to just using two *ngIfs (which works fyi)... why can't I have an event on my ng-template?
I've replaced the changeViewState() with a property and changed the (click) event to an (activate) and (mouseover) event... It seems to not like any (event) on the ng-template...

I've copy-pasted the problem code around my application and it errors each time.

'problem code':

```
<div *ngIf="(this.stateUserReqValid === 'userInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'orgInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'supInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'secInfo'); else ele"
  class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('userInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">
  <h4 class="font-weight-light">
    <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">1 </span> User Information &nbsp;
    <span class="icon-accept user-man-accept"></span>
  </h4>
</div>
<ng-template #ele class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('userInfo')" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">
  <h4 class="font-weight-light">
    <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">1 </span> User Information &nbsp;
    <span class="icon-accept user-man-accept"></span>
  </h4>
</ng-template>
```

new-user.component.html

```
<!-- <app-page-header [icon]="'fa fa-users'"></app-page-header> -->
<!-- <app-page-header [heading]="'User Management'" [icon]="'fa fa-users'"></app-page-header> -->



<!-- BLADE LAYER 1 -->
<div class="blade" [@routerTransition]>
  <div class="blade-header">
    <!-- <div class="blade-header" [ngClass]="{'is-minimized-header':minimizeVar}"> -->
    <h3>NEW USER REQUEST</h3>
  </div>


  <!-- [ngClass]="{'feature-nav-button': portalState =='portal-a', 'click-portal-style': portalState =='portal-a'}" -->

  <!-- BLADE Contents -->
  <div class="blade-contents">

    <!-- <div *ngIf="((this.stateUserReqValid != 'userInfo') || (this.stateUserReqValid != 'orgInfo') || (this.stateUserReqValid != 'supInfo') || (this.stateUserReqValid != 'secInfo'))" class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('userInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">1 </span> User Information &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-right user-man-chevron"></span>
      </h4>
    </div> -->

    <div *ngIf="(this.stateUserReqValid === 'userInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'orgInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'supInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'secInfo'); else ele"
      class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('userInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">1 </span> User Information &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-accept user-man-accept"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <ng-template #ele class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('userInfo')" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">1 </span> User Information &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-accept user-man-accept"></span>
      </h4>
    </ng-template>


    <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid != 'orgInfo'" class="userManHover" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='orgInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='orgInfo'}">2 </span> Organization &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-right user-man-chevron"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <!-- <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid === 'userInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'orgInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'supInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid === 'secInfo'" class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('orgInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='orgInfo'}"> -->
    <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid === 'orgInfo'" class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('orgInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='orgInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='orgInfo'}">2 </span> Organization &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-accept user-man-accept"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>


    <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid != 'userInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid != 'orgInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid != 'supInfo' || this.stateUserReqValid != 'secInfo'"
      class="userManHover" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='supInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='supInfo'}">3 </span> Supervisor &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-right user-man-chevron"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid === 'supInfo'" class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('supInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='supInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='supInfo'}">3 </span> Supervisor &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-right user-man-chevron"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid != 'secInfo'" class="userManHover" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='secInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='secInfo'}">4 </span> Security Profiles &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-right user-man-chevron"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="this.stateUserReqValid === 'secInfo'" class="userManHover" (click)="changeViewState('secInfo');" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='secInfo'}">
      <h4 class="font-weight-light">
        <span class="blade-2-number" [ngClass]="{'blade-2-activated-number' :  stateUserReq =='secInfo'}">4 </span> Security Profiles &nbsp;
        <span class="icon-right user-man-chevron"></span>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="stateUserReq === 'userInfo'">
  <new-user-req></new-user-req>
</div>
<div *ngIf="stateUserReq === 'orgInfo'">
  <new-user-org-info></new-user-org-info>
</div>
<div *ngIf="stateUserReq === 'supInfo'">
  <new-user-supervisor-info></new-user-supervisor-info>
</div>
<div *ngIf="stateUserReq === 'secInfo'">
  <new-user-security-info></new-user-security-info>
</div>
```

new-user.component.ts

```
import { UserReqViewStateService } from './../../../shared/services/UserManagement/UserReqViewState.service';
// import { PageHeaderModule } from './../../../shared/page-header/page-header.module';
import { UserManagementModule } from './../user-management.module';
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition, slideToRight, slideToLeft } from '../../../router.animations';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

import { NewUserReqComponent } from './new-user-req/new-user-req.component';  //bringing accessability/form validation state from child
import { UserReqValidStateService } from '../../../shared/services/UserManagement/UserReqValidState.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'new-user',
  templateUrl: './new-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-user.component.css'],
  host: {
    'class': 'blade-container'
  },
  animations: [slideToRight()]
})
export class NewUserComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {

  stateUserReq: string = 'userInfo';

  stateUserReqValid: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private viewstate: UserReqViewStateService, private validstate: UserReqValidStateService) { }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log(this.stateUserReqValid)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewstate.currentState.subscribe(stateUserReq => this.stateUserReq = stateUserReq)
    this.validstate.currentState.subscribe(stateUserReqValid => this.stateUserReqValid = stateUserReqValid)
  }

  changeViewState(state) {
    this.viewstate.changeState(state);
  }


  private scrollToSectionHook() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const tree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
        if (tree.fragment) {
          const element = document.querySelector('#' + tree.fragment);
          if (element) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'nearest' });
            }, 500);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }


}
```

user-management.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NgModule, Type, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { GridAllModule } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import {
  GridModule, ToolbarService, EditService, SortService, GroupService, FilterService, PageService,
  ContextMenuItem, PdfExportService, ExcelExportService, ContextMenuService, ResizeService,
  DataSourceChangedEventArgs, DataStateChangeEventArgs
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';


import { UserManagementComponent } from './user-management.component';
import { PageHeaderModule } from './../../shared';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


// import { NewUserComponent } from './new-user/new-user.component';
// import { PendingUserComponent } from './pending-user/pending-user.component';
// import { ProcessUserComponent } from './process-user/process-user.component';
// import { NewUserReqComponent } from './new-user/new-user-req/new-user-req.component';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NewUserOrgInfoComponent } from './new-user/new-user-org-info/new-user-org-info.component';
import { NewUserSupervisorInfoComponent } from './new-user/new-user-supervisor-info/new-user-supervisor-info.component';
import { NewUserSecurityInfoComponent } from './new-user/new-user-security-info/new-user-security-info.component'; //??????????
import { NewUserComponent } from './new-user/new-user.component';
import { PendingUserComponent } from './pending-user/pending-user.component';
import { ProcessUserComponent } from './process-user/process-user.component';
import { NewUserReqComponent } from './new-user/new-user-req/new-user-req.component';
import { UserManagementBladeComponent } from './user-management-blade/user-management-blade.component';
import { UserReqValidStateService } from '../../shared/services/UserManagement/UserReqValidState.service';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PageHeaderModule,
    GridModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgbModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserManagementComponent, NewUserComponent, ProcessUserComponent, PendingUserComponent, NewUserReqComponent, NewUserOrgInfoComponent, NewUserSupervisorInfoComponent, NewUserSecurityInfoComponent, UserManagementBladeComponent],
  providers: [EditService, ToolbarService, SortService, GroupService, FilterService, PageService,
    ContextMenuService, PageService, ResizeService, PdfExportService, ExcelExportService, UserReqValidStateService]
})
export class UserManagementModule {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { PageHeaderModule } from './shared/components/page-header/page-header.module';

import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

// Support imports
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// import services
import { WebApiService } from './shared/services/webapi/web-api.service';
import { UserService } from './shared/services/UserManagement/User.service';
import { LogService } from "./shared/services/logging/log.service";
import { LogPublishersService } from "./shared/services/logging/publishers/LogPublishers.service";

// Security
import { GWIAuthService } from "./shared/services/authService/gwiAuth.service";

// Import Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';

// Import feature modules
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';

// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserManViewStateService } from './shared/services/UserManagement/UserManViewState.service';
import { Guardian } from './shared/services/authService/guardian';
import { UserReqViewStateService } from './shared/services/UserManagement/UserReqViewState.service';
import { UserReqValidStateService } from './shared/services/UserManagement/UserReqValidState.service';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NotFoundComponent, LandingComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    LayoutModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PageHeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    LogService,
    LogPublishersService,
    WebApiService,
    GWIAuthService,
    UserManViewStateService,
    UserReqViewStateService,
    UserReqValidStateService,
    Guardian
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Why not add (click) event in h4 tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can bind the event to  wrapper container(e.x. HTML tag)

```html
<ng-template #ele  >
 <div (click)="changeViewState('userInfo')" class="userManHover" [ngClass]="{'userManSelect': stateUserReq =='userInfo'}">
  ...
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This was not working in my application.  I kept getting "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined".  Then I made a plunker which doesnt quite work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1djvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake, the wrapper container need inside in ng-template, I updated to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1u9i7

Comment: For anyone wondering.... the error I was getting in my application, "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined", was actually for the [ngClass] on the ng-template. I just moved that to the h4 as well.

Comment: yap, you can't put element attributes on an ng-template that it doesn't map to an actual DOM element.

Comment: if you interesting about deep knowledge, you can check [What is the difference between a view, a host view and an embedded view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027581/7291379)

Comment: I am! Thank you

Comment: if you try to put event for ng-container it does not work.
  <ng-container  (click)='sayHi()'>
click me
</ng-container>

Comment: @ChunbinLi this helpled me...thanks! Could you please explain why is this working? I only added some #element reference to my ng-template and it's not undefined anymore

Comment: @Smithy Would you give me an example that you use? If your question is why not have an event on ng-template. The answer is : **ng-template doesn't map to an actual DOM element.**

Comment: @ChunbinLi I use pretty much exactly thing as you do, so <ng-template #someElement>  , when there was no #someElement it was not working, but with it does. "Bind the event to wrapper container" was the sentence that I found a bit confusing

Comment: ng-template is not an actual DOM element, it doesn't have any DOM Event(ex. click event), so I add a DOM element (div) then move click event to div from ng-template.